# Implement a UIContainerView to support multiple login/signup/loggedin screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

Right now I'm using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to create a side menu for my application. I have this working good. The next thing I want to do is implement 4 different ViewControllers for Login, Sign Up, Logged In, and Forgot Password, then based on whether or not the user is already logged into the device programmatically switch between these controllers.

So, initially on the SWRevealViewController menu I have an table view item "User" which is linked to the "Logged In" View Controller. Upon initially loading this controller I check whether or not a user is already logged in, if they are, I simply continue with this View Controller, if not, I programmatically instantiate my "Login" view controller to prompt the user to login. This is where the problem lies. Because when I programmatically instantiate my "Login" view controller, I lose the ability to connect with the SWRevealController and thus the side menu is completely gone.

LoggedInViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundView.frame.size.height / 10

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        //menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        //menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)     /* Once this is complete, my Login controller no longer knows about SWRevealViewController */

            //self.addChildViewController(viewController)           /* Doing this does not allow for animation */
            //self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
            //self.didMoveToParentViewController(viewController)

        })
    } else {
        usernameLabel.text! = PFUser.currentUser()!.username!
    }
}
```

By calling self.presentViewController I lose my connection to SWRevealViewController.

LoginViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundView.frame.size.height / 10.0
    usernameTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    passwordTextField.delegate = self

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {   // This now returns nil
        //menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        //menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

My first thought was to put all 4 of these ViewControllers into a ContainerView and then manage them from that. But is this the best way to do this? Is there another way where I can programmatically instantiate these controllers while being able to animate between them and retain the reference the SWRevealViewController?

Comment: I don't use the library, but it looks like it provides a method called `setFrontViewController:animated:` which implies by its name that you can use it to present the login vc.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I think that works. I see now you can even implement the protocol to customize the transitioning animation. Thanks!